# Mysql: Get result of Checksum into Insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write an insert query, where I want to add checksum of another table.

My Engine is InnoDb not MyIsam .

So checksum in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES are all null.

But when I run query like

```
CHECKSUM TABLE TABLE_NAME
```

it gives me checksum of that table. I wanted to know How I can store that value.
Or Is there any way I can find changes to table. 
Triggers is a way. But when there are changes they are more than one so, I drop and run my scripts and they create all tables. (all tables are created from csv excel sheet and they are changing. )

So far I have tried this :

```
INSERT INTO `XYZ` (`TABLE_NAME`, `ABC`, `CHECKSUM`)
VALUES 
('X',
  1, 
  (SELECT Checksum FROM CHECKSUM TABLE 'X')
);
```

But It is giving me following error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds   to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'TABLE 'X') )' at line 1

Checksum of a table can be calculated using query in following link:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checksum-table.html

Can anybody please help me? Thanks .

Comment: What are you trying to do? AS the error states, your syntax is wrong, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do so I can't correct it. Perhaps you wanted to say `SELECT checksum FROM checksum WHERE someCol = 'X'`?

Comment: @McAdam331 I wanted to add checksum of a table into another table using insert query . Checksum table table_name gives table and checksum as result . so I am want to grab checksum from that result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL store checksum of tables in another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237712/mysql-store-checksum-of-tables-in-another-table)